# How to delete result query from sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete this result form database.Please help me.

```
select *
FROM          stock_batch AS a
INNER JOIN     
(
    SELECT    stockid, Max(batchid) AS batchid
    FROM      stock_batch
    GROUP BY  stockid
) AS b
ON            a.stockid = b.stockid
AND           a.batchid < b.batchid
```

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We need to know what your database vendor is (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.), because the syntax for delete is specific to each vendor.

Answer (score 1):

If your using SQL SERVER you can do by using CTE like below.

```
WITH CTE AS(
     select *
     FROM stock_batch AS a
     INNER JOIN     
     (
        SELECT    stockid, Max(batchid) AS batchid
        FROM      stock_batch
        GROUP BY  stockid
     ) AS b
     ON            a.stockid = b.stockid
     AND           a.batchid < b.batchid)

     delete from stock_batch WHERE STOCKid IN(SELECT stockid FROM CTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sql server` then you can do like below. Just replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE a`. Note : `a` is alias that you have used for table.

```
DELETE a
FROM          stock_batch AS a
INNER JOIN     
(
    SELECT    stockid, Max(batchid) AS batchid
    FROM      stock_batch
    GROUP BY  stockid
) AS b
ON            a.stockid = b.stockid
AND           a.batchid < b.batchid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this standard dml delete script

```
DELETE 
FROM stock_batch
WHERE stockid in 
    (select stockid from 
        (select a.stockid
            FROM          stock_batch AS a
            INNER JOIN     
            (
            SELECT    stockid, Max(batchid) AS batchid
            FROM      stock_batch
            GROUP BY  stockid
            ) AS b
            ON a.stockid = b.stockid
            AND a.batchid < b.batchid
        ) as t1
    )
```

Comment: Error Code : 1093
You can't specify target table 'stock_batch' for update in FROM clause
(0 ms taken)

Comment: try now, i added table alias t1

Answer (score 0):

You can Simple use DELETE Like below
 DELETE  a
FROM          #stock_batch AS a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT    stockid, Max(batchid) AS batchid
    FROM      #stock_batch
    GROUP BY  stockid
) AS b
ON            a.stockid = b.stockid
AND           a.batchid < b.batchid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the most recent batch for each stock, I would recommend one of the following:

```
with todelete as (
      select sb.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stockid order by batchid desc) as seqnum
      from stock_batch sb
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Or:

```
delete sb from stock_batch sb
    where sb.batchid < (select max(sb2.batchid)
                        from stock_batch sb2
                        where sb.stockid = sb2.stockid
                       );
```

Both of these can take advantage of an index on `stock_batch(stockid, batchid)`.  However, if you are deleting many rows, this may still be slow.  In that case, there are other approaches that might be faster.